# Handle both null and empty string values with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I am working with JAXB generated classes from schema and got stuck with following problem. I am trying to handle both null and empty string values with single element.

What I want to achieve is to be able to marshal both null and empty string values and receive the same while unmarshaling.

`Element("key1", "value1") -> <element key="key1">value1</element>`

`Element("key2", "") -> <element key="key2"/>`

`Element("key3", null) -> <element key="key3" xsi:nil="true"/>`

Schema xsd:

```
<xs:element name="element" nillable="true">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="key" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

So far I get the following results, if value is null or "" I get the same xml:

`Element("key1", null) -> <element key="key1"/> -> Element("key1", "")`

`Element("key2", "") -> <element key="key2"/> -> Element("key2", "")`

Any idea if it is even possible with this xml structure? The only idea I have is to change structure to something like this, but it will generate more useless classes to deal with.

```
<element>
   <key>key1</key>
   <value>value1</value>
</element>
```

**Edit**

With given schema change it works as expected. The question if it is possible with original structure is still open.

```
<xs:element name="element">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="key" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string" nillable="true"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

```
<element>
    <key>key1</key>
    <value xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
</element>
<element>
    <key>key2</key>
    <value/>
</element>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Since by default XJC does not bind a nillable element to `Element`, but to `JAXBElement<Element>`, can you add the JAXB annotated class you use to represent `<element>` to your question?